# ifelse returns unexpected values

Tags: dplyr

Basically, I would like to create a new column based on an existing column. I want the new column to be changed only if it meets some conditions.

I tried both ways below, but either one worked - it returned a numerical value instead of the value of the existing column for the FALSE condition. I read some posts indicating that ifelse removes the attributes of the column, which could causes the issue.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

BTW, it works fine if the existing column is numerical.

```
attach(iris)
library(dplyr)

# Approach 1
d1 = iris %>%
  mutate(s = ifelse(Species == "versicolor", "ver", Species))

View(d1)

# Approach 2
d2=iris
d2$s = ifelse(d2$Species == "versicolor", "ver", d2$Species)
View(d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Columns containing characters are loaded in R as factors, so, they should be converted into characters, if you wish to operate on them as on characters:

```
attach(iris)
library(dplyr)

iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

# Approach 1

d1 = iris %>%
  mutate(s = ifelse(Species == "versicolor", "ver", Species))

View(d1)

# Approach 2
d2=iris
d2$s = ifelse(d2$Species == "versicolor", "ver", d2$Species)
View(d2)
```

Clustering and some other ML methods will require the opposite conversion - `as.factor`.